# Import from various version of python

Tags: python

I have written code in Python. In the import section i have the following:

`import snappy
import xlrd`

The xlrd is a library that can only be used by Python 3.6.  The snappy is a libary that can only be used by Python 2.7. How i can use both Python 2.7 and 3.6?

Comment: You can use `python-snappy` which is compatiable with python 3. Check [this](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy) out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a program with various versions of Python at once.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't, you have to use a compatible version of the library you need.

You can use `python-snappy`

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to run a script with different Python versions, take a look at this repository for snappy which states that Python 2.7 and 3 are both supported -

https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy

You can try implementing the snappy and xlrd libraries using Python 3.6.